# Is this the volume of a solid of revolution of a sector about a point in space along phi

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Consider this sector S what's area is the following:
$$
A = \frac{1}{2}r^2\theta
$$
Where theta is in radians.
I would like to create a solid out of this sector by rotating it about $\phi$ with the following:
$$
V =\int_{0}^{2\pi} \Big[\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta\Big]\phi \:\:d\phi
$$
which evaluates to:
$$
V =\frac{r^2\theta \phi^2}{4} 
$$
and then let $\phi = 2\pi$ (upper bound of the integral):
$$
V =\frac{r^2 \pi^2\theta}{2}
$$
Is this correct?

Edit: Add picture, red is S, light green is surface, dark green is inside cross section.  This is a bad picture, the dotted lines should be straight not curved.
[Image of the solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mwaw.png)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to notice about your solution is that it is dimensionally incorrect. Volume should be proportional to $r^3$.

A solution can had very quickly with Pappus's (2nd) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2πR$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2πRA$.

Without any further ado, the properties of the sector are

$$
R=\frac{2r\sin\alpha}{3\alpha}\\
A=\alpha r^2\\
V=2\pi RA=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \sin\alpha
$$

where $\alpha$ is the half-angle of the sector.